# Display Binary Raw data html

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have a blob in my database and would like to store the data in a variable to display it. When I ask for the blob straight it can display, but when I try to store it in a variable and display it cannot.

Here is my code

```
$http.get("/getImage")
  .then(function (response) {

    $scope.image = response.data;

   // document.body.appendChild(img);
  });
```

my html

```
<img src="{{image}}" alt="Image one" width="300" height="200">
```

Any Ideas. This is how the data looks like.

```
����[This is how the data looks like][1]
```

Thank you.

Comment: I doubt you can directly show the binary as a source of img. Convert the binary to base64 string and then show it like src="data:image/png;base64,{{image}}"

Comment: how can i convert binary